# C++ - 2 classes 1 file

Tags: c++

Suppose I want something of this sort, in one `.cpp` source file:

```
class A {
    public:
        void doSomething(B *b) {};
};

class B {
    public:
        void doSomething(A *a) {};
};
```

Is there anyway of doing this without splitting it into two separate files, and without receiving a compiler error (syntax error on `doSomething(B *b)`)

Comment: Me, obviously :-)  Or whichever answer you like the most.

Comment: @Yuval, accept the person that was the first to answer your question.

Comment: @Yuval - accept the first answer that answered your question correctly and helpfully.

Comment: Or accept the "best" answer in your opinion. Jiri was fastest and most concise. Others provide links or explanations of why that answer is correct. Whatever you prefer :-)

Comment: A year has passed, and not a single acknowledgment of the reference in the question title...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

put at the first line:

```
class B;
```

Answer (score 12):

If I remember well, you can 'pre-declare' your class B.

```
class B; // predeclaration of class B

class A
{
   public:
      void doSomething(B* b);
}

class B
{
    public
      void doSomething(A* a) {}
}

public void A::doSomething(B* b) {}
```

Then, your class 'A' knows that a class 'B' will exists, although it hasn't been really defined yet.

Forward declaration is indeed the correct term, as mentionned by Evan Teran in the comments.

Comment: good answer, so you get the +1. But for reference the term is "forward declaration"

Answer (score 4):

forward declare one class before other with

```
class B;
or
class A;
```

But still you won't be able to implement

```
void doSomething(B *b)
```

using only forward declaration of B. So you have to put definition of doSomething below full class A declaration

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  You need a forward declaration:

```
class B; // add this line before A's declaration

class A {
    public:
        void doSomething(B *b) {};
};

class B {
    public:
        void doSomething(A *a) {};
};
```

Answer (score 3):

[The C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/misc-technical-issues.html#faq-39.11) answers this question and others.  I'd seriously considering reading that thing end to end, or getting the book and doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a forward declaration like

```
class B;
class A {
  void Method( B* );
};
class B{
};
```

but you will only be able to declare pointer and reference variables for B then. If you want more (like a method that dereferences B* variable) you can provide a declaration only and define methods later in the same file - at the point where both classes declaration is already available.

Answer (score 1):

You need to forward declare B.

```
class B; 

class A
{
public:        
   void doSomething(B *b) {}
};

class B 
{    
public:        
   void doSomething(A *a) {}
};
```

(And BTW, you don't need the semi-colons after the member function curly braces. :) )

Answer (score 0):

Add another declaration of B before A:

```
class B;

class A {
    public:
        void doSomething(B *b) {};
};

class B {
    public:
        void doSomething(A *a) {};
};
```