# unknown type name on defining object of another class from same file in C++

Tags: class, object

In my one c++ file named "two_elements.cpp", I am defining two classes within same file, and the code goes like below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstream>

class A{
    public:
        void methodA(){
            //do something
        }
};

class B{
    public:
        A a_obj;
        a_obj.methodA();
};
```

This throws the following error:

```
error: unknown type name 'a_obj'
```

I folowed the following stack overflow links comprehensively, but could not find a work around:

[Unknown type name class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336244/unknown-type-name-class)

[unknown type name 'class'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40311370/unknown-type-name-class)

[C++ - 2 classes 1 file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677325/c-2-classes-1-file)

Please note most of these questions had classes in the individual header files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstream>

class A{
    public:
        void methodA(){
            //do something
        }
};

class B{
    public:
        A a_obj;
        B(){
            a_obj.methodA();
        }
};
```

An instance needs to be called inside a constructor or a function in c++.